How could I install library libssl on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.8 through a configuration file?
Wicked_pdf pdf generator needs libssl and is not finding it on production and I can't find how to install the library.
I am using Ruby 3.2.2 and rails 6.0.0 on a Amazon Centos server, wicked_pdf says it needs the library to render pdfs.
The error inside logs file:
Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: pid 596870 exit 127 /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.7/bin/wkhtmltopdf_centos_6_amd64: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ):
I'm aware that wicked_pdf is no longer being suported but we are trying to get it working on production.
I already installed the library compat-openssl with a .config file in the projects .ebextentions folder but that did'nt do the trick.
The command inside the .config file in .ebextensions/install_compat-openssl11.config:
packages:
rpm:
compat-openssl11: https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos-stream/9-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/compat-openssl11-1.1.1k-4.el9.x86_64.rpm
